# Why is the TableAttribute in the Entity Framework Dll?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity

Is there a good reason why the Table attribute (which can be used to map a POCO class to the correct database name/schema) is in the EntityFramework.dll?

Doesn't this prevent you from creating a Domain project that simply contains your entities with no dependency on a specific data access technology? For example, if I use this attribute I don't believe the classes would be portable to Silverlight.

Is this an oversight, or am I missing something?

I realize I could use the fluent API to circumvent this, but the attribute seems preferable for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because the TableAttribute has been added in EF 4.1. It belongs to namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and would probably have been added to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly if EF 4.1 had been part of a regular .NET Framework release. But because EF 4.1 was released independently from a Framework update they couldn't touch the framework core assemblies. So, it is for now in EntityFramework.dll but still in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace, so somehow independent from Entity Framework. Maybe it will be moved into `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` with the next .NET Framework version.

For now, if you want to decorate your POCOs with the TableAttribute you must reference EntityFramework.dll. I wouldn't consider this as dependency from Entity Framework as long as you don't use the "real" EF stuff (`DbContext`, etc.) in your custom assembly.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected something like that, and yeah it's not a huge deal on the full .Net platform, but it does create a dll dependency and in Silverlight I believe it will be a problem since you wouldn't be able to reference EntityFramework.dll.

Comment: It's in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll in .NET 4.0, but that's no better. It's NOT supported by the SQL CLR!  It complains if I try to deploy it as a safe assembly that "CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataTypeAttribute' in safe assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' has a static field '_dataTypeStrings'. Attributes of static fields in safe assemblies must be marked  readonly in Visual C#, ReadOnly in Visual Basic, or initonly in Visual C++ and intermediate language. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 6211)".

Answer (score 1):

This does cause a problem for Silverlight.

For those with struggling with this one you must, for the moment, use the fluent API to do the mapping.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccount>().ToTable("BankAccounts");
    modelBuilder.Entity<CreditCard>().ToTable("CreditCards");
}
```

HTH.

Comment: This is a great solution for both the original question and the Silverlight issue of adding attributes of all kinds e.g. Entity<BankAccount>().Property(b=>b.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None).  Just don't forget to call base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) after tagging your entities.