# TableAttribute in EF 4.4, where is the old constructor with the TableName?

Tags: entity-framework

My project needs ef and we need to update to EF4.4 because of using .NET 4.0. So in this case, i changed the references to the new assembly. I get an build error that my TableAttribute(TableName) does not exists anymore. There is another Table attribute in DataAnnotations.Schema which does not take the table name. Im localizing automatically by using that Table attribute, so where is it gone in EF Version 4.4. Is there an alternative where i can add an aspect to the entity which specifies the table which is assigned later?

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034041/why-is-the-tableattribute-in-the-entity-framework-dll) would help. BTW on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.aspx) TableAttribute seems to appear in version 4.5 of the framework.

Comment: But what does EF5 (EF4.4) now? How can you set the name of the Table in the new EF Version? There must be an possibility to set the name of the Table over an attribute and not alone by using mapping by hand. Because we can't change to .NET 4.5, it does not help to get implemented in this version. The EF4.4 is the EF 5 for .NET 4.0, and how does this special version implement this functionallity?

Comment: you should browse the entityFramework dlls (using objects explorer in VS) to search where is the attribute.